# Java Core - что нужно знать?

Tags: java

Что нужно знать, чтобы можно было сказать  "Я знаю Java Core"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ну на самом деле понятие Java Core очень расплывчатое. Кто-то считает, что это все то, что описано в JLS, кто-то берет за основу SCJP, кто-то какие-то собственные метрики. Есть вообще люди, которые называют это Java Fundamentals, а к Core относят еще и ООП, работу с коллекциями и основы мультипоточности. Тут здесь все очень субъективно.
Но думаю, если сможете ответить на все вопросы из этого [интервью](http://voituk.kiev.ua/2008/03/14/java-interview-questions/), то вполне уверенно можете говорить о том, что знаете Java Core.

Comment: Отличный набор вопросов, спасибо.

Comment: @Farrock, не забудьте принять ответ.

Comment: Да, конечно. Но хотелось бы больше мнений тк действительно "понятие Java Core очень расплывчатое".

Так что, возможно будут еще варианты ответов...

Answer (score 3):

В рамках книги Брюса Эккеля "Философия Java".

Answer (score 0):

Тогда уже 2 томник Хорстманна. Он так и называется Java Core

Answer (score 0):

Наверное к ответу к данному вопросу прежде всего нужно отнести синтаксис java и средства которые отличают этот язык от других ооп языков программирования. Как говорилось раньше это скорее всего проявление ооп в java, коллекции, многопоточностью. Вообще написано множество книг. И точно ответить на этот вопрос мало кто сможет , можно взять книги которые обхватывают java и почитать разделы , станет примерно понятно.